# Can't get Facebook data fast enough

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to get Facebook's user name and photo in my code. I'm able to do both, but the problem is the segue is called before the data return to me! So when I go to the next screen, the variables are nil! Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //MARK: - FB Button customization:

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil){
        print("Not logged in")
    }
    else{
        print("This is where you perform a segue.")
        fetchProfile()
        performSegueWithIdentifier("nextfb", sender: self)
    }
}

func fetchProfile() {
    print("fetch profile")

    let parameters = ["fields": "email, name, picture.type(large)"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        if let name = result["name"] as? String {
            self.nome = name
            print(name)
            print(self.nome)
        }
        if let email = result["email"] as? String {
            self.email = email
            print(email)
        }

        // pega a imagem do usuário:
        if let data = result["picture"]?!["data"]
        {
            if let url = data!["url"] as? String
            {
                let profilePictureURL = url
                let imgURL = NSURL(string: profilePictureURL)
                let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL!)
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                print(image)
                self.foto = image!
            }
        }
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "nextfb" {

        print("\nO NOME É: \(nome)\n")
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! HomeViewController
        vc.name = self.nome
        //vc.photo = self.foto
    }
}
```

The second View Controller prints a nil value for the name AND THEN the first View Controller prints the name and the image! (when I'm already in the second View Controller)

How can I pass those variables via segue properly?? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Simply put the `performSegueWithIdentifier("nextfb", sender: self)` at the place where the facebook data has loaded, e.g. at the end of the block you pass to `FBSDKGraphRequest` (make sure you make the UI-call on the main thread).

Comment: Not sure if I did it right but still not working. Only have `performSegueWithIdentifier("nextfb", sender: self)` now exactly where`FBSDKGraphRequest` ends but still loading the 2nd VC with no data and only then prints the user's name!

Comment: do you have it ***inside*** the call to `FBSDKGraphRequest`? Before the second closing `}`!?

Comment: No, I have it when it finishes because by putting it inside this error shows up: `Implicit use of 'self' in closure, use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit`. Do I have to modify the sender for what? I didn't understand this, shouldn't the segue be the sender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `performSegueWithIdentifier("nextfb", sender: self)` in the wrong place. You are checking the existence of your access token, and if you aren't logged in, you are invoking the segue.

Instead of that, you should do this:

```
if let data = result["picture"]?!["data"]
    {
        if let url = data!["url"] as? String
        {
            let profilePictureURL = url
            let imgURL = NSURL(string: profilePictureURL)
            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL!)
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            print(image)
            self.foto = image!
            performSegueWithIdentifier("nextfb", sender: self) 
        }
    }
```

This way you only go to the next controller when your data has successfully populated on your view controller.

Comment: What should be the `sender` in this case? By doing this the xcode indicates an error: `Implicit use of 'self' in closure, use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit`

Comment: The sender can be whatever you want it to be - it just depends what data you need on the next view controller. I would pass `nil` for now to make sure the segue is called correctly, but then you can decide what to pass through afterwards.

Comment: You two are geniuses!! It works properly now! Thanks so much for the help!!